# how does convn function worksin matlab

Tags: matlab

I spent whole day trying to figure out how convn function works in 'valid' mode for order 3 tensor. I have an input i of size 3*3*2 and a filter w of size 2*2*2 but the output size after convolution is 2*2 as shown in the image links bellow. I just need to understand how the dot product of convolution was performed on both channels of the input 1. please if you can demonstrate how the first entry of the output was calculated by convn function. note that i am rotating w 180 degrees so as to perform cross correlation instead of convolution just for ease of hand calculations check up. many thanks in advance.this image include simple example of input and filter values [im1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXLyY.jpg) and this image include result after convn [im2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK4r7.jpg)

EDIT
this a copy from the command window

```
K>> i

i(:,:,1) =
 1     5     4
 7     8     9
 1     2     6


i(:,:,2) =
 3     4     6
 7     1     3
 1     2     6

K>> w
w(:,:,1) =
 1     2
 5     3


w(:,:,2) =
 4     3
 8     4

K>> convn(i,rot90(w,2), 'valid')

ans =

   156   162
    88   134
```

I definitely understand what convolution is and what it does both in discrete and continues form, and I also understand the different modes of matlab convn 'full' 'same' and 'valid'. when I switched to tensor of more than order two, I got confused. I trued by hand many check ups but I couldn't get the correct result as given by the function itself

PROBLEM SOLVED:
when we decompose convolution we get this:

```
K>> convn(i(:,:,1),rot90(w(:,:,1),2), 'valid')

ans =

    70    80
    34    54



K>> convn(i(:,:,1),rot90(w(:,:,2),2), 'valid')

ans =

   107   132
    68    99
```

now convolution on whole 3d tensor will give:

```
K>> convn(i,rot90(w,2), 'valid')

ans =

   156   162
    88   134
```

if we want to check by hand the output result,  it makes more sense to add the first entries of the results obtained from decomposed convolution.

for example the first entry of the result is 156 however adding 107+70=177 which is not rue and this what was confusing me all the time.

when we use rot90 not only filters are flipped but also how computation is done. meaning that the FIRST channel (matrix) of the filter w will be convolved with the SECOND channel of the input and THE SECOND channel of w will be convolved with the FIRST channel of the input as shown bellow:

```
 K>> convn(i(:,:,1),rot90(w(:,:,2),2), 'valid')

ans =

   107   132
    68    99

K>> convn(i(:,:,2),rot90(w(:,:,1),2), 'valid')

ans =

    49    30
    20    35
```

now 49+107=156, and 20+68=88 and so, hence these match the output result on whole 3d tensor.

conclusion take away: using N-D convolution with rot90 will flip all dimensions.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of text, you can copy-paste that text from MATLAB.

Comment: If you know what convolution is, you'll understand there are a certain number of shifts for which the filter `w` completely fits inside the input `i`. This is what the 'valid' mode returns.

Comment: Cris Luengo just show how the first entry of the result was computed, because i got confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element `(i,j,k)` of the output of `convn` for a 3D `input` is computed by:

```
[n,m,l] = size(w);
w_flipped = flip(w);
            % ^ except this flip is over each dimension
output(i,j,k) = sum( input( i+(1:n)-1, j+(1:m)-1, k+(1:l)-1 ) .* w_flipped );
                % ^ except this sum is over all dimensions
```

`output` can be computed for each `i`, `j`, `k` such that the indexing into `input` can be done. If  you select a different option for `convn`, indexing will exceed the `input`, and zeros are filled in for the unknown values.

Comment: Cris Luengo thanks for your reply. honestly I couldn't make sense of what you have written over here. you know things are more clear with examples. please could you use the example I gave in my post, and apply what you have said just for the first entry of the output. it would be so kind of you

Comment: I think maybe your problem is that you are using `rot90`, this flips the first two dimensions. You also need to flip aliñar the 3rd dimension. `flip(w,3)`. @abdelazizbotalb

Comment: Cris Luengo thanks so much that was exactly the problem, I have clarified it in my post. I cant vote you up because I need more than 15 reputation. thanks a lot again.